# Commit transaction started in dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

The following code runs as expected. The row is inserted.

```
create table #t1(a datetime2)

declare @s nvarchar(max) = N'
-- Some expensive remote query should not be in the transaction
begin tran
insert #t1 select getdate()';

exec (@s);

commit; -- replace commit to rollback will rollback the transaction

select * from #t1
```

However, it got the following error?

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Line 31
>
> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

**Update:**
I found that the `insert` statement in the dynamic SQL will not be run if I put the code in a try/catch block. However, it still got the error.

```
begin try

    declare @s nvarchar(max) = N'
    -- Some expensive query should not be in the transaction
    begin tran
    insert #t1 select getdate()';
    exec (@s);

    commit

end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_LINE(), @@TRANCOUNT
    if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        rollback
end catch
select * from #t1
```

Comment: What are you trying to avoid or prevent by going this route?

Comment: Can you not contain the 'exec (@s)' within a transaction instead?

Comment: Do your string stuff and finally do something like...BEGIN TRAN EXEC(@s) COMMIT

Comment: @Leonidas199x, I just want part of the code in `@s` in the transaction.

Comment: Even if you wanted to, you can't prevent the dynamic SQL from executing in the context of your transaction. SQL Server does not have autonomous transactions, so short of creating a brand new connection, you can't have statements execute independently.

Comment: @RossBush, No. I've updated the question with my final attention. I was testing without try/catch.

Comment: Here's a simpler repro: `EXEC('BEGIN TRAN')`. The batch ends with the `EXEC`, and the server considers it an error for the batch not to have committed. You can't start a transaction in an `EXEC` unless it also finishes there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, actually if I replace `commit` to `rollback`, it will really roll back the transaction in my first example. (The second one works differently anyway)

Comment: Yeah, something funky is going on with how the transaction is actually treated -- it is still active after the `EXEC`, but the engine nevertheless issues an error about the `@@TRANCOUNT` mismatch immediately after the `EXEC`. Furthermore, this error dooms the transaction regardless of `XACT_ABORT`, so that even `TRY .. CATCH` will not allow you to proceed anyway (you get "uncommittable transaction"). Moral of the story: don't start transactions in an `EXEC` that don't finish there, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> the engine nevertheless issues an error about the @@TRANCOUNT mismatch
>   immediately after the EXEC. Furthermore, this error dooms the
>   transaction regardless of XACT_ABORT

The second statement here is not true, as the first OP's example shows, the transaction started in dynamic code can be successfully committed in the outer scope. So the transaction is not doomed, it's commitable.

I did not find the question in the OP. If it's about what to do with the 266 error, the answer is just ignore it.

266 error message is informational only, you can see it here:
[Rollbacks and Commits in Stored Procedures and Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187844(v=sql.105).aspx):

> If @@TRANCOUNT has a different value when a stored procedure finishes
>   than it had when the procedure was executed, **an informational error
>   (266) occurs**

So what is happend here is the server saves  `@@TRANCOUNT` when you execute a stored procedure/dynamic sql and when you return to outer scope it controls if `@@TRANCOUNT` is the same as when you started sp/dynamic code, if it's not the case it raises the 266 error that is "terminating nothing at all error" and is considered as informational only.